# CVXPY error "Cannot multiply two non-constants" while solving SVM dual

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, convex-optimization, cvxpy

I'm trying to solve the SVM dual problem with CVXPY.

[image: formula of the dual problem]

Below is the Python code:

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx

# note: X and Y are numpy arrays generated for testing purpose
# calculating guassian kernal
def kg(a, b, theta=1):
    sim = np.exp( -0.5 * np.dot(a, b) / (theta ** 2))
    return sim

# generating kernal matrix
def k_mat(x, k_func=kg):
    m = x.shape[0]
    mat = np.zeros((m, m))
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(m):
            mat[i, j] = k_func(x[i, :], x[j, :])
    return mat

k=k_mat(X)

# setup parameters
a = cvx.Variable(m)
C = cvx.Parameter(sign="positive")
C.value = 0.01

# start convex optimization
obj = cvx.Maximize(cvx.sum_entries(a) - \
      0.5 * cvx.mul_elemwise(Y, a).T * k * cvx.mul_elemwise(Y, a))
constraints = [a>=0, a<=C, cvx.sum_entries(Y, a)==0]
prob = cvx.Problem(obj, constraints)

prob.solve()
print(a.value)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3066, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-44-d3b220364629>", line 4, in <module>
    obj = cvx.Maximize(cvx.sum_entries(a) - 0.5 * cvx.mul_elemwise(Y, a).T * k * cvx.mul_elemwise(Y, a))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cvxpy/expressions/expression.py", line 43, in cast_op
    return binary_op(self, other)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cvxpy/expressions/expression.py", line 224, in __mul__
    raise DCPError("Cannot multiply two non-constants.")
cvxpy.error.DCPError: Cannot multiply two non-constants.
```

It seems that cvxpy cannot support the quadratic form optimization for with kernel matrix. However I've seen people using cvx in Matlab solving the same problem on page 13(35) of this presentation:

http://users.isy.liu.se/en/rt/schon/CourseMLlund/le5.pdf

I'm very new to cvx. Please help me correct this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Found the solution.

Problem 1

I made a stupid mistake, wrong definition of gaussian kernel, should be:

```
def kg(a, b, theta=1):
    sim = np.exp(np.dot((a - b), (a - b)) / (2 * theta ** 2))
    return sim
```

Problem 2

The correct quadratic form should be. (I really hope cvx formula will be compatible with numpy conventions)

```
cvx.quad_form(cvx.mul_elemwise(Y, a), k)
```

Comment: I am using quad_form  but still getting DCPError. I am trying to the same thing you did.